# How to compare a sentence with a paragraph and get its probability in terms of correctness?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, tensorflow, pytorch

This is my first post on stackoverflow network and I am dealing with a machine learning.

Lets say I have a paragraph describing a rabbit and tortoise story. The story concludes that tortoise is a winner.

Now I want to train ML engine based on this paragraph. If I provide a statement as "Rabbit won the race", how can it show me the correctness of my statement in terms of probability of correctness?

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex problem related to [Natural Language Understanding (NLU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_understanding). The key part in such a system is certainly [textual entailment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_entailment), but it could also use techniques such as [Question Answering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering) and [summarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization).

I'm not aware of any direct model or tool to carry out this task exactly, so I think you will have to study the literature in these fields.